# Is the future of the web application going the same as the desktop application?

Tags: web-applications, mobile

I've noticed an increase in mobile applications being released that offer high value features, but without any corresponding web based version.

Was just reading about a new medical app for iPhone that allows doctors to share medical images, and had this idea been done 5 years ago it surely would have been a web application. Now it's released purely on iPhone without any web alternative.

It's been years since I've had a client request a desktop application, and everything has been web based, but today all future projects involve some kind mobile solution.

How much longer should I recommend clients to continue investing in web based applications?

Comment: "Fortune telling" is not a very constructive topic, so voting to close.

Comment: Fortune telling is extremely constructive, reopen and let me know as soon as you find a highly accurate fortune teller, I would love to hear how I die.. Voting to close until then.

Comment: Don't forget that there can be components of an overall system that still have web components, these just aren't necessarily visible to the end user.  Consider that in the sharing of those medical images, aren't they likely going through some kind of server requiring some kind of HTTP call?  Just something to consider here.

Comment: @DocBrown lol, I can not argue with the Doc!

Comment: I think platform trends are a great topic...not so sure there's a question that can be answered.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The web offers a lot of pros. It is easier to make a multi-platform web application then a MP desktop application.

The problem with the web is that you are constrained by the browser's boundaries. For example, you don't have access to the file system.

If you really need access to the file system in a web application, you can use java or flash bu they are quite undesirable in a website since they are proprietary plugins that may not work on all platforms.

The web application won't be able to entirely replace a good old desktop app for a long time since the web is growing really really slowly.